# Batch file, rename a file on many pc's and copy a new version

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

This is what I have scripted thus far from bits I've used in the past. I have basic knowledge and build and research things as I go.

I currently receive a syntax error after the echo renaming / copying.

Can you please help?

```
echo SWIFT UPDATER
echo off
echo off
echo Ready to go?
pause

for /F "tokens=*" %%1 in (pc_list.txt) do (
echo Renaming / Copying files to %
Ren /f "\\%%1\c$\Program Files (x86)\SWIFT\NSL\jnsl\wsnaddr.txt" "c$\Program Files (x86)\SWIFT\NSL\jnsl\wsnaddr.old"

copy "\\server\infratech\Servereng\APPS-UK\Swift Update\wsnaddr.txt" "\\%%1\c$\Program Files (x86)\SWIFT\NSL\jnsl\" >> "\\server\infratech\Servereng\APPS-UK\Swift Update\log.txt"
)
:::: End Copy ::::::
@echo off
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors in this script.

> for /F "tokens=*" %%1 in (pc_list.txt) do (

`for` statements must use an alpha value for the variable (see the [MS documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true)).  Not a numeric variable - which are preserved for parameters passed to a batch file.

Try something like this instead.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (pc_list.txt) do (
```

And ...

> echo Renaming / Copying files to %

needs to be changed to

```
echo Renaming /Copying files to %%a
```

And...

> Ren /f "\%%1\c$\Program Files (x86)\SWIFT\NSL\jnsl\wsnaddr.txt" "c$\Program Files (x86)\SWIFT\NSL\jnsl\wsnaddr.old"

needs to be changed to:

```
IF EXIST "\\%%a\c$\Program Files (x86)\SWIFT\NSL\jnsl\wsnaddr.old" del /f /q "\\%%a\c$\Program Files (x86)\SWIFT\NSL\jnsl\wsnaddr.old"
ren "\\%%a\c$\Program Files (x86)\SWIFT\NSL\jnsl\wsnaddr.txt" wsnaddr.old
```

Because there is no `/f` parameter and the second parameter should be a simple file name rather than a full path (see [MS documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490987.aspx)).
 (and of course I've changed the `%%1` to match the new `%%a` variable)

I'm also confused by all the `echo off` statements.  Usually you'd only have one `@ECHO OFF` at the beginning of the script.  But, that shouldn't cause any errors.  It just makes for confusing output sometimes.

I'd recommend looking over the `<command> /?` output from a command line if you haven't discovered that yet.  It should have the same information as the MS documentation I've linked to.

Comment: the syntax of the command is incorrect

Comment: See my updated answer.  There are a lot of errors in this script.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, this seems to have worked

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (pc_list.txt) do (

ren "\%%a\c$\Program Files (x86)\SWIFT\NSL\jnsl\wsnaddr.txt" wsnaddr.old

```
copy "\\server\infratech\Servereng\APPS-UK\Swift Update\wsnaddr.txt" "\\%%a\c$\Program Files (x86)\SWIFT\NSL\jnsl\" >> "\\server\infratech\Servereng\APPS-UK\Swift Update\log.txt"
)
```